# get full path up to given element

Tags: json, jq

I have exported bookmarks from Firefox which in my case is quiet large JSON. I'm interested in the object with guid `_0no-4e9woLW` in a JSON such as this one:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "zoo": {
        "guid": "_0no-4e9woLW",
        "title": "frontend",
        "index": 3,
        "dateAdded": 1614198626454000,
        "lastModified": 1619505016472000,
        "id": 16518,
        "typeCode": 2,
        "type": "text/x-moz-place-container",
        "children": [
          {
            "guid": "2L7ZsYTM2RX0",
            "title": "css child override parent style",
            "index": 0,
            "dateAdded": 1614198648005000,
            "lastModified": 1614198648005000,
            "id": 16519,
            "typeCode": 1,
            "type": "text/x-moz-place",
            "uri": "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=css+child+override+parent+style"
          },
          {
            "guid": "x3JHTAezzyI8",
            "title": "css child parent inheritance",
            "index": 1,
            "dateAdded": 1614198648096000,
            "lastModified": 1614198648096000,
            "id": 16520,
            "typeCode": 1,
            "type": "text/x-moz-place",
            "uri": "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=css+child+parent+inheritance"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get somehow full path up to `"guid": "_0no-4e9woLW"`? guid keys are uniq in JSON. My goal is to type something like `jq '["full path I've somehow previously obtained"]["children"].title'`

And I will obtain:

```
css child override parent style
css child parent inheritance
```

Of course I could do this manually but I'm too lazy.

Comment: You are asking `full path up to "guid"`, but haven't shown  the structure of your JSON. How do we determine, under which path `guid` is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `recurse` allows to get to the object easily :

```
jq -r 'recurse |
       select(type=="object" and .guid == "_0no-4e9woLW")
       .children[].title' firefox.json
```

Comment: That just looks up an object by guid, which isn't what was asked. But if that's what needed, all you need is `.. | objects | select(.guid == "_0no-4e9woLW") | .title`

Comment: @ikegami If you have tried my solution, you'll see it outputs exactly what OP wanted. Yours just gives a single value `null`.

Comment: Re "*you'll see it outputs exactly what OP wanted.*", Oh, I know. Or I assumed as much. I just said it's overly complicated. /// Re "*Yours just gives a single value `null`.*",  [Not true](https://jqplay.org/s/gPWRR2pxVC)

Comment: Sorry I got null due to the test data I constructed. Anyway, yours does not get what OP expected. I don't agree that my solution is overly complicated.

Comment: It's not subjective. `select(type=="object")` is objectively more complicated than `objects`. It has 1/3 of the expressions, and the only expression is as trivial as they get /// `.children[].title`, whateves.

Comment: You should not compare `select(type=="object")` against `objects, but `select(type=="object" and .guid == "_0no-4e9woLW")` (mine) against `objects | select(.guid == "_0no-4e9woLW")` (yours). Will you still say mine is more complicated than yours ?

Comment: You should, as the `select` is part of the mental context required to undertstand the `type=="object"`

Comment: Even more important is the wider context, which is the reason why I suggested you make the second comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Without the whole knowledge of the JSON, something like this should work when using `path` family of functions i.e. `getpath/1`

```
( paths | select(.[-1] == "guid") ) as $p | 
  if getpath($p)  == "_0no-4e9woLW" then getpath($p[:-1] + ["children"])[].title else empty end
```

The construct above means, select all those paths containing the leaf key named `guid` and store them in a variable and filter only the path whose value turns out to be `"_0no-4e9woLW"`. On the selected path, trim the child node(`$p[:-1]` removes `"guid"`) and add the node `"children"` and get the value at the new path constructed (using `getpath/1`). Extract the `.title` field from the JSON value

<sup>[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NFZGlkzeGP)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

- To access a node by guid:

  ```
  .. | objects | select( .guid == … )
  ```

  So you'd use the following to get the title of `_0no-4e9woLW`'s children:

  ```
  .. | objects | select( .guid == "_0no-4e9woLW" ) | .children[].title
  ```

  [Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/K7xs_qZyrA)
- To save a path:

  ```
  path( … )               # As JSON
  ```

  ```
  path( … ) | join(".")   # As dotted path
  ```

  Replace `…` with an expression that returns the node(s) for which you want the path.

  For example,

  ```
  path( .. | objects | select( .guid == "_0no-4e9woLW" ) )   # [ "foo", "bar", "zoo" ]
  ```

  [Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/JpOFbdirZW)

  ```
  path( .. | objects | select( .guid == "_0no-4e9woLW" ) ) | join(".")   # "foo.bar.zoo"
  ```

  [Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/vthDqCY5L5)
- To grab an object using its path:

  ```
  getpath( … )                                      # From JSON
  ```

  ```
  getpath( … | split(".") | map(tonumber? // .) )   # From dotted path
  ```

  Replace `…` with an expression that returns the previously saved path.

  For example,

  ```
  getpath( [ "foo", "bar", "zoo" ] ).children[].title
  ```

  [Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/6iMljl5rYI)

  ```
  getpath( "foo.bar.zoo" | split(".") | map(tonumber? // .) ).children[].title
  ```

  [Demo on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/g1YS1v6GPI)

Comment: I guess some logic is broken here. I've tried  `path( .. | objects | .guid == "_0no-4e9woLW" )` but it returns `jq: error (at <stdin>:39): Invalid path expression with result false exit status 5` If I do instead `path( .. | objects )` then I get some output but not desired one. https://jqplay.org/s/ijCi1e_r66

Comment: Should be `path( .. | objects | select(.guid == "_0no-4e9woLW") )`. Adjusted answer.

Comment: Now this one does not work `path( .. | objects | select( .guid == "_0no-4e9woLW" ) ) | join(".")`

Comment: Not so. [It does work](https://jqplay.org/s/vthDqCY5L5)

Answer (score 0):

```
json2jqpath.jq file.json 
.
.foo
.foo|.bar
.foo|.bar|.zoo
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.dateAdded
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.guid
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.id
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.index
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.lastModified
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.title
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.type
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.typeCode
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.uri
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.dateAdded
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.guid
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.id
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.index
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.lastModified
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.title
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.type
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.typeCode
```

Shows `guid`  appears as a leaf in more than one unique path.
If there were only one you would be done
(assuming you knew the value existed)
with multiple paths you need to check that the value exists
and it is to your object of interest.

```
json2jqpath.jq file.json | grep guid
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.guid
.foo|.bar|.zoo|.guid
```

Appending your given value to the paths returns objects containg them

```
jq '.foo|.bar|.zoo|.children|.[]|.guid="_0no-4e9woLW"' file.json 
{
  "guid": "_0no-4e9woLW",
  "title": "css child override parent style",
  "index": 0,
  "dateAdded": 1614198648005000,
  "lastModified": 1614198648005000,
  "id": 16519,
  "typeCode": 1,
  "type": "text/x-moz-place",
  "uri": "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=css+child+override+parent+style"
}
{
  "guid": "_0no-4e9woLW",
  "title": "css child parent inheritance",
  "index": 1,
  "dateAdded": 1614198648096000,
  "lastModified": 1614198648096000,
  "id": 16520,
  "typeCode": 1,
  "type": "text/x-moz-place",
  "uri": "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=css+child+parent+inheritance"
}


jq '.foo|.bar|.zoo|.guid="_0no-4e9woLW"' file.json 
{
  "guid": "_0no-4e9woLW",
  "title": "frontend",
  "index": 3,
  "dateAdded": 1614198626454000,
  "lastModified": 1619505016472000,
  "id": 16518,
  "typeCode": 2,
  "type": "text/x-moz-place-container",
  "children": [
    {
      "guid": "2L7ZsYTM2RX0",
      "title": "css child override parent style",
      "index": 0,
      "dateAdded": 1614198648005000,
      "lastModified": 1614198648005000,
      "id": 16519,
      "typeCode": 1,
      "type": "text/x-moz-place",
      "uri": "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=css+child+override+parent+style"
    },
    {
      "guid": "x3JHTAezzyI8",
      "title": "css child parent inheritance",
      "index": 1,
      "dateAdded": 1614198648096000,
      "lastModified": 1614198648096000,
      "id": 16520,
      "typeCode": 1,
      "type": "text/x-moz-place",
      "uri": "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=css+child+parent+inheritance"
    }
  ]
}
```

[json2jqpath.jq](https://github.com/TomConlin/json_to_paths)